# issues with center aligning content

Tags: html, css

I've the below HTML.

```
<div class="para align-center">SCHEDULE 1 <span class="align-right">[r.32]</span></div>
<div class="para align-center">PART I</div>
```

and the below CSS

```
.para {
  text-indent: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0.85em;
}
.para + .align-right {
  margin-top: 1.2em;
}
.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
div.align-center span.align-right {
  float: right;
}
```

Here I'm trying to center align the `SCHEDULE 1` word, it is in center but there is some left inclination, and the second div `PART 1` is in the exact center. Please let me know how can I get the first div in center and the right aligned text has to be there in right on same line. When I delete that right aligned text, `SCHEDULE 1` appears in exact center.

```css
.para {
  text-indent: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0.85em;
}
.para + .align-right {
  margin-top: 1.2em;
}
.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
div.align-center span.align-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="para align-center">SCHEDULE 1 <span class="align-right">[r.32]</span>
</div>
<div class="para align-center">PART I</div>
```

Comment: now you can see my answer please sir

Comment: please now check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with using [position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) field in CSS

HTML:

```
    <div class="para align-center">SCHEDULE 1 <span class="align-right">[r.32]</span>
</div>
<div class="para align-center">PART I</div>
```

CSS:

```
.para {
  text-indent: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0.85em;
}
.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
div{
    position: relative;
}
div.align-center span.align-right {
  float: right;
}

div span.align-right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Please look at the demo code
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rzersxas/)

Comment: Hi, is there a way doing without using position, since my tool doesn't accept `position`

Comment: @user3872094 what do you mean "my tool doesn't accept position"? What  tool do you use?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `.para +  .align-right` remove `+`

```
Css:

.para {
  text-indent: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0.85em;

}
.align-center {
  text-align: center;

}

div.align-center span.align-right {
   float:right;
    margin-left:-38px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/fuv96rfo/8/)